# Page not scrolling with selenium python on ubuntu 20

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I have a script that is to scroll to the bottom of a webpage. It is working perfectly on Windows 10 but when I implemented same script on Ubuntu 20 it does every other thing but scroll the page. I concluded it is a problem with ubuntu 20  and want to know if any other person had faced the same challenge and it there is a possible way around it, be it any other way to get to the bottom of a webpage? Thank you in anticipation.

Snippet from the code:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)`

same code worked as expected in windows 10 but on Ubuntu 20 it does nothing and gives no error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only press key down one time. So i'm not sure why it working on windows.
This is two other solutions i usually use and it work on both Windows and Ubuntu as far as i check.

**Solution 1: Using Javascript executor**

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

**Solution 2: Pressing combination of ctrl+end**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END)
```

Comment: Really it is in a loop:
```for x in range(500):
           driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html').send_keys(Keys.DOWN) ```
I am going to explore your suggestion when I connect to the server. Thanks so much.

Comment: Okay, I get it. The solution I provide will go straight to bottom of the page, so you not need to but it in loop. Check if it working

Comment: Thank you friend, its now working, I actually had to change find_element_by_css_selector('html') to find_element_by_css_selector('body'). Thank you once again.

Comment: My pleasure  :))